# How to split an array into chunks of a given length in python?

Tags: python

What is the fastest and shortest method to turn this:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

for example into this:

```
ids = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

by giving the input `2` as the fixed length.

Of course there are some easy ways to make this but none of them occur to me as fast or pretty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/4983469

Comment: Thank you! How could I have not found that

Comment: Because you did not google? It is the first result for `split an array into chunks of a given length in python stackoverflow`.

Comment: I swear I did. I searched for it for 10 minutes. :c

Comment: :) no problem man. hope you got the answer  here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why don't you try out a list comprehension?

**Example:**

```
[ids[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(ids),2)]
```

**Output:**

`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]`

Comment: Yeah just found it thanks to leoOrions comment too.
stackoverflow.com/a/312464/4983469
But Thanks!

Comment: range should also include a step I think. (If you posted this as answer and not direction)

Comment: @lllrnr101 I thought that was obvious but alright :)

Comment: Your output and code do not  match. That is all I wanted to say. Because range() is still not using step. So the sub-lists still overlap which were not overlapping in OPs question. But since it is accepted I think  it solves his problem.

Comment: @lllrnr101 You are right I fixed it, I was a bit in a rush so my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

bad but effective:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_ids = []


function = lambda x, y: [x, y]

for i in range(0, len(ids), 2):
    try:
        new_ids.append(function(ids[i], ids[i + 1]))
    except IndexError:
        new_ids.append(ids[i])
ids = new_ids
print(ids)
```